How to access auth user in inertial react
I want to access the auth user to my navigation page, How to do this in inertia react?
this code works for Vue but doesn't work in react js
$page.props.auth.user

thanks

The question is not clear. Please provide more information

Hi what I meant is accessing the auth user in my front end.

Please edit to include a complete minimal reproducible example of the relevant code you are working with and more complete details regarding the issue and any debugging steps and details you have taken.

I got by using inertia usePage
import { usePage } from "@inertiajs/react";

const user = usePage();

now i can access the auth user  {user.name}
